# DB2 LUW version 10.5.0.10 - Get Warning (Not found) Line in Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, warnings, backtracking, sqlcode

I'm trying to determine the line in a stored procedure or the last SQL-statement which is causing a warning / not found. As a workaround I'm using temporary variables which I manually set to determine in which part of my stored procedure a warning occurs.

```
-- Create an ErrorLog table
Create Table SCHEMA.ErrorLog_lrc_test                                                        
  (                                 
   ErrSQLCODE     Integer ,                                   
   Codepart    Char(1),                             
   Type           Char(1) ,                                  
   MsgText        VarChar(1024));

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHEMA.test_warning(IN divisor INT)
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
-- Define variables
DECLARE codepart_var Char(1);

DECLARE test_INT INT;

-- Define sqlcode
DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER;
       
--Define Warning-Handler
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING, NOT FOUND 
    BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO SCHEMA.ErrorLog_lrc_test(ErrSQLCODE, Codepart, TYPE, MsgText) 
        VALUES(SQLCODE, codepart_var, 'W', SYSPROC.SQLERRM(SQLCODE));
    END;
 
-- Set temporary variable to 'a' to get part of code where warning occured
SET codepart_var = 'a';

-- Create Not Found (Sqlcode 100)
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.ErrorLog_lrc_test
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM "SYSIBM".SYSDUMMY1
WHERE 1 = 0 ;

END 

call SCHEMA.test_warning(0);

SELECT *
FROM SCHEMA.ErrorLog_lrc_test;
```

I get the following:

| ERRSQLCODE | CODEPART | TYPE | MSGTEXT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | a | W | SQL0100W No row was found for FETCH, UPDATE or DELETE; or the result of a query is an empty table. |

I know that for errors there is a function DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE that you can use for tracing errors. Unfortunately that function doesn't trace warnings. Also there is a function DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK, but this doesn't work neither.

Is there another/better way to log the specific line or SQL-statement in a stored procedure which is causing a warning / not found?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such ability for Warnings built-in at the present time, as far as I'm aware. Consider carefully your motivation here.

A programmer can catch warnings by using exception handlers (or multiple exception handlers) **inside** the routine(s), and could decide to log such events (or in extremis, to convert them into errors by raising new exceptions, which would then be visible via `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT*` methods). But that would be unwise, except in a development environment perhaps.

Your routines could have a `continue handler` for warnings, in which you check the SQLSTATE, and conditionally decide to log specific SQLSTATES. It may be foolish to record SQLSTATE '02000' (sqlcode 100 - no rows found) as this is benign like most warnings.  But some warnings might suggest other issues, e.g. with data quality/conversion/truncation or optimization issues that may be interesting to record.

I'm unaware of any tooling to help with this, or provide line-numbers for warnings, or integrate such work for client side enquiry.

A DBA can (for Db2-LUW) use other tools at the Db2-server to more closely observe executing statements and packages. For example monitoring, `db2pd`, `db2cos`, auditing etc. But that route seems like using a sledgehammer to crack a possibly non-existent nut, hence the need to double check your motivation.